# Java instanceof operator

Tags: java, instanceof, comparison-operators

Is there a valid class Type variable that can be used with the `instanceof` operator? For Example:

```
String s = "abc";

Class<?> classType = String.class;

if (s instanceof classType) {
    //do something
}
```

as an alternative to this:

```
if (s.getClass() == classType) {
    //do something
}
```

Would there be any performance benefit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing is not actually the same. Consider what happens with subclasses (I know you can't subclass `String`, so in the `String` case it doesn't matter).

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

B b = new B();
b instanceof A // true
b.getClass() == A.class // false
```

If you have an object and you want to know if it is an instanceof a certain type and you have the `Class` object, you can use the `Class#isInstance` method.

In either case, I expect performance differences to be insignificant.

Comment: so X.class.isInstance(objectX) is faster than doing objectX instanceof X?

Comment: They are different. You use the first if you have the class type, since you can't do objectX instanceof xClass. It helps for dynamic checking when the class you're checking against is unknown at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear, lets say this: java.lang.String.cass.isInstance(objectX)  compared to objectX instanceof java.lang.String. Which would you say is faster?

Comment: I would guess off hand that instanceof is since it's a built-in java construct, but you could run some tests to find out.

Comment: b.getClass() = A.class // false should be b.getClass() == A.class // false (== instead of =)

Answer (score 3):

There's also

```
Class<?> classType = String.class;

if (classType.isInstance(s)) {...
```

As for performance, I'd expect the differences between any of these to be negligible.