# How to create method with return type as any subType of superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Pre information.

```
public abstract class Person {}
public class A extends Person{}
public class B extends Person{}
public class C extends Person{}

public X getPersonByType(String type){
    //This Method will return either A or B or C based on type
    //what should X be ?    
}
```

I need to create a method which takes in a `String` and returns an object which is a subtype of `Person`.

More Information.
Each of the classes A B C have an attribute public List roles. These cannot be moved upto the Person class as I require these uniquely named for (JPA many to many table).

Now If possible, i would not like it to return `person` as I would not be able to access the roles attribute (Person does not know about it). I would also prefer a solution (if possible) which does not require me to cast or use instanceOf (again if possible).

P.S tried `<? extends Person>` but Eclipse gave me error "return type of method is missing"

Comment: Make it return `Person`.

Comment: see [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) and [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: @gangqinlaohu: There's no indication that generics are appropriate here.

Comment: please see more information added. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `Person X`. As `Person` is an abstract type it **can't** be instantiated. You can have `Person X` as a `reference` that should point to an object of any of the concrete implementation of `Person` which are `A` `B` & `C` in your case. This is the beauty of `run time polymorphism`. Based on your input at the run time it would create an `object` of any of the `A`, `B` or `C` class and use reference `X` to point to that object.I would suggest you go through [Factory Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) which will give you more information about how this type of design works in real life scenario.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was over thinking using Generics, but this is a nice simple solution. Thx, it worked.

Comment: I have similar code that works when I return the abstract super type for 1 element. However, when I try to return a List<Person> then it doesn't work. I am getting a compile error stating: Required List<Person> found List<A> even though A extends Person. I also tried adding <T extends Person> List<T> to my method and then I get the message: Required List<T> found List<A>... any ideas on how I can do this with a collection?

Answer (score 3):

`public Person getPersonByType(String type)` should work fine because all your return types extend `Person`.

You can also add an additional class parameter if you want to avoid `instanceof` checks after calling this method:

```
public <T extends Person> T getPersonByType(String type, Class<T> type) {
   ...
   // cast result to T
}
```

Using this way you would be able to assign the return type to a subclass directly:

```
C c = getPersonByType("c", C.class);
```

Be aware that this can cause `ClassCastExceptions` if you pass in a String and a Class parameter that don't match each other.

Comment: Correct declaration is: `public <T extends Person> T getPersonByType(String type, Class<T> type) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

`X` should be `Person`.

since `Person` is an abstract class and can't be instantiated it will always return one of your subtypes.

If you need to know what `getPersonByType` returned from your calling method, you can use the [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751550/java-instanceof-operator) operator

Answer (score 1):

```
public Person getPersonByType(String type){
// analyze type and return appropriate instance...
    if ("A instance".equals(type)) {
        return new A();
    }
...

}
```