# Java: call a method of a not-defined type

Tags: java

Let's take this code

```
MyClass object;
object=new MySubClass();
```

Where MySubClass extends MyClass.
After this, i'd like to call a method of MySubClass
object.myMethod();

i get a compile error, but in runtime it should work. How can i call myMethod without an explicit cast like this?
((MySubClass)object).myMethod()

Comment: Why don't you declare object as MySubClass?

Comment: i can't, i don't know the specific type, i know only that it will be of type MyClass. I think the right answer is something about Reflection http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html#obtaining but can't get the point

Comment: Is it possible to make MyClass as abstract and add the method myMethod() as abstract in MyClass?

Comment: can't, i'm working with standard classes :P

Answer (score 2):

> How can i call myMethod?

You can declare the object as type of `MySubClass`:

```
MySubClass object = new MySubClass();
```

**Why?** Because the object when you do:

```
MyClass object = new MySubClass();
```

the object is of type `MyClass`, so can only call methods from `MyClass`.

Look at this example: let's say you have a class `Person` and a subclass `Employee` with an extra field called `salary`(and its respective getters/setters). If you declared an object like:

```
Person p1 = new Employee();
```

then you wouldn't like to call its method `getSalary()` because in fact, `p1` is of type `Person`. You can't use "specific"(declared in subclass) methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

If the method is defined in the sub-class, then you will need an [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751550/java-instanceof-operator) the sub-class -

```
MyClass object; // <-- Make this MySubClass object; **OR**
object=new MySubClass();

// instanceof
if (object instanceof MySubClass) {
  MySubClass msc = (MySubClass) object;
  msc.doSomeMethod(); // <--
}
```

or you might use an [abstract method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) in `MyClass` -

```
public abstract class MyClass {
  public abstract void doSomeMethod();
}
```

Of course, `MySubClass` must still have `doSomeMethod()`

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass {
  public void doSomeMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

then you could use

```
object.doSomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `object` to be of type `MySubClass`.

```
MySubClass object = new MySubClass();
```

Or, you can test if your `MyClass` is really a `MySubClass`, then cast to `MySubClass` so you can call the method.

```
if (object instanceof MySubClass)
{
    MySubClass sub = (MySubClass) object;
    sub.myMethod();
}
```

Or, you can define `myMethod` in the class `MyClass`, so that any `MyClass` instance can call that method.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `object` as having type `MyClass`, you are telling the compiler to forget that `object` is anything but a `MyClass`, that there may not be any other methods not on `MyClass`, and the like.  You've *told* the compiler to do this.

Your options are to tell the compiler something different, by declaring `object` as having type `MySubClass`, or to do the cast.  There aren't really other options.